# How to edit a txt file using JTextField with a specific format?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, filereader

I am creating a inventory program that involves the cashier and the admin mode. The admin mode can change the item name, price and stocks of an item. All items are stored in a txt file.

The content of the txt file (it has slashes to separate names, prices etc):

```
 ID     Item Name                 Price   Stocks
00001 / Xbox 360                 / 7999  / 10
00002 / Xbox Series X            / 25999 / 20
00003 / Playstation 4 Pro        / 22999 / 15
00004 / Nintendo Switch          / 17999 / 27
00005 / Nintendo Switch Lite     / 11999 / 15
```

I read and display the items using a JTable. The column headers are added in the code:

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\zagad\\IdeaProjects\\DATABYTES\\stock\\consoles\\consoles.txt";
                File file = new File(filePath);
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) productTable.getModel();
                    Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

                    for (int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++) {
                        String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
                        String[] dataRow = line.split("/");
                        productTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(21);
                        productTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(120);
                        productTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(30);
                        productTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(30);
                        model.addRow(dataRow);
                    }
```

Here is a reference image of the layout:

[image]

It has a JTable and four JTextFields. Is there any idea that I can edit the txt file directly what the user inputs from the JTextFields with the corresponding location of items in the txt file?

Any idea is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure you don't want to hear this but here it goes anyway: **"Use a database".** You'll love yourself for doing it.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Hello! Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it is a project that we need to code solely in Java alone without using any other programs or languages. It's just I need something that will edit the txt file using `JTextFields`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Hello! I've sent another email to you. Thank you :)

Comment: **'Do Not'** reference **anything** here in comments that has been discussed through E-Mail. That is NOT what the comments section is for. Have the comfort of knowing that I am looking at your situation and will work on it as time permits. You need to realize that you're not the only person on the planet and, if you want daily updates then you will need to pay for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your file data lines (data records) are formatted in a specific way with various spacing, you should be trimming off any leading or trailing white-spaces from the columnar data as it is read to be placed within the JTable. Currently, you split each data file row with:

```
String[] dataRow = line.split("/");
```

This will not remove all the white-space padding applied to each column of data that was placed upon that data when it was formatted and saved to the file. This padding will need to be dealt with (removed) when you actually need to work with that data. It is far better to remove al this white-space padding when you carry out the split, like this:

```
String[] dataRow = line.split("\\s{0,}/\\s{0,}");
```

You have disclosed very little information with regards to what your particular application really contains like data types (although most are obvious), what is already created (classes, member/instance variables, fields, statics, etc), the code used to save your data from JTable to file, etc, etc. This therefore leaves the whole works open to assumptions or 101 questions which I in particular will not ask. Because of this, the code I present below will be basic and more geared to a Console styled inventory system rather than a GUI styled system. You will need to apply the code to specific areas of your application where you see fit.

To start with, you need an **Items** class. Since each Inventory Item contains specific attributes such as **ID**, **Item Name**, **Price**, and **Quantity** (in Stock), you need a means to hold this data in memory so that it can be worked with in a fashion where any piece of data can be quickly acquired and manipulated. Your class might look like this:

```
public class InventoryItems {

    private String id;
    private String itemName;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public InventoryItems() {    }

    public InventoryItems(String id, String itemName, double price, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuffer("").append("ID: ").append(id).append(", Item Name: ")
                                   .append(itemName).append(", Price: $").append(price)
                                   .append(", Quantity: ").append(quantity).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Returns instance data as a String in the format specified in your supplied 
     * format string.
     * 
     * @param formatString
     * @return
    */
    public String toString(String formatString) {
        if (formatString == null || formatString.equals("")) {
            return toString();
        }
        // String Format Specifiers must be separated 
        // with a single white-space.
        switch (formatString.split("\\s+").length) {
            case 1:
                return String.format(formatString, id);
            case 2:
                return String.format(formatString, id, itemName);
            case 3:
                return String.format(formatString, id, itemName, price);
            case 4:
                return String.format(formatString, id, itemName, price, quantity);
            default:
                return toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need helper methods to: load your file data (inventory records), retrieve a specific record, retrieve specific item attributes, save specific item attributes, save records, etc, etc. These methods might look like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class InventoryDemo {

public enum ErrorMsg {
    LOAD_ERR("Inventory Items have not been loaded in yet!"),
    NOT_ADMIN("Invalid Operation! Admin Status Required!"),
    ID_EXISTS("Invalid ID! That ID Already Exists!"),
    NAME_EXISTS("Invalid Item Name! That Name Already Exists!");

    private String msg;

    ErrorMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String msg() {
        return msg;
    }

}

private String encoding = "UTF-8"; // options: "US-ASCII", "UTF-8", "UTF-16"
private final List<InventoryItems> items = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean isInAdminMode = true;
private String dataFile = "InventoryItems.txt";
private String ls = System.lineSeparator();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // App is started this way to avoid the need for statics.
    new InventoryDemo().startApp(args);
}

private void startApp(String[] args) {
    if (!loadDataFile()) {
        System.err.println("Error Loading: " + dataFile);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This code is run from the startApp() method" + ls 
                     + "located within the InventoryDemo class. Its" + ls
                     + "intent is to demonstrate the how the methods" + ls
                     + "withint this class function." );
    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println("Available Inventory Items");
    System.out.println("=========================");
    String[] allItems = getAllInventoryItems();
    if (allItems != null) {
        for (String strg : allItems) {
            System.out.println(strg);
        }
    }

    pressAnyKey(input);

    showFormattedTable();

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Available Inventory Items (with formated ID & Name)");
    String header = String.format("%-7s %-26s", "ID", "Item Name");
    String topLine = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "="));
    String underline = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"));
    System.out.println(topLine);
    System.out.println(header);
    System.out.println(underline);
    allItems = getAllInventoryItems("%-7s %-26s");
    if (allItems != null) {
        for (String strg : allItems) {
            System.out.println(strg);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(topLine);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific Record (by ID: 00004)");
    System.out.println("=========================================");
    String itemString = getItemString("00004");
    System.out.println(itemString);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific ID (by Name: Playstation 4 Pro)");
    System.out.println("===================================================");
    itemString = getItemID("Playstation 4 Pro");
    System.out.println(itemString);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific Name (by ID: 00004)");
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    itemString = getItemName("00004");
    System.out.println(itemString);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific Price (by ID: 00003)");
    System.out.println("========================================");
    double itemprice = getItemPrice("00003");
    System.out.println(itemprice);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific Quantity (by ID: 00002)");
    System.out.println("===========================================");
    int itemQuant = getItemQuantity("00002");
    System.out.println(itemQuant);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Change Name for: 'Playstation 4 Pro' at ID: "
            + "'00003' TO 'Some Kinda Game-Box'");
    System.out.println("============================================"
            + "================================");
    itemString = getItemString("00003");
    System.out.println("Current Name: -->  " + itemString);
    setItemName("00003", "Some Kinda Game-Box");
    itemString = getItemString("00003");
    System.out.println("Name is Now:  -->  " + itemString);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    String itemToAdd = "00006/LG LED 60\" Television/70555.0/08";
    System.out.println("Add a new Inventory Item (duplicate ID's are not allowed).");
    System.out.println("Adding (with 'NO Auto-ID-Increment'): "
            + itemToAdd);
    System.out.println("======================================"
            + "======================================");
    if (addInventoryItem(itemToAdd)) {
        showFormattedTable();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not add (" + itemToAdd + ") to Records List!");
    }

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    itemToAdd = "DYSON 430 Vacume/65437.0/6";
    System.out.println("Add a new Inventory Item (duplicate ID's are not allowed).");
    System.out.println("Adding (with 'Auto-ID-Increment'): "
            + itemToAdd);
    System.out.println("======================================"
            + "=======================");
    if (addInventoryItem(itemToAdd)) {
        showFormattedTable();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not add (" + itemToAdd + ") to Records List!");
    }

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Delete an Inventory Item ID (based on Item ID: 00006).");
    String itemIDToDelete = "00006";
    if (deleteInventoryItemID(itemIDToDelete)) {
        showFormattedTable();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not delete record ID (" + itemIDToDelete + ") from Records List!");
    }

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Delete an Inventory Item Name (based on Item Name: DYSON 430 Vacume).");
    String itemNameToDelete = "DYSON 430 Vacume";
    if (deleteInventoryItemName(itemNameToDelete)) {
        showFormattedTable();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not delete record Item Name (" + itemNameToDelete + ") from Records List!");
    }
}

private void showFormattedTable() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("   Available Inventory Items (with formatting)");
    String header = String.format("%-7s %-26s %-8s %-5s", "ID", "Item Name", "Price", "Stock");
    String topLine = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "="));
    String underline = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"));
    System.out.println(topLine);
    System.out.println(header);
    System.out.println(underline);
    String[] allItems = getAllInventoryItems("%-7s %-26s $%-9s %-5s");
    if (allItems != null) {
        for (String strg : allItems) {
            System.out.println(strg);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(topLine);
}

/**
 * Deletes the Inventory Item in Records List and data file that contains the 
 * supplied Item ID.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param idToDelete (String) The ID Number of the record to delete.<br>
 * 
 * @return (Boolean) True if successful and False if not.
 */
public boolean deleteInventoryItemID(String idToDelete) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return false;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).getId().equals(idToDelete)) {
            items.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
    return true;
}

/**
 * Deletes ALL Inventory Items in Records List and data file that contains the 
 * supplied Item Name.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param nameToDelete (String) The Item Name to delete (case insensitive).<br>
 * 
 * @return (Boolean) True if successful and False if not.
 */
public boolean deleteInventoryItemName(String nameToDelete) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return false;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameToDelete)) {
            items.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
    return true;
}

/**
 * Admin Rights required!<br><BR>
 * <p>
 * Adds a Inventory Item to the Records List and database file.<br><br>
 * This method can produce a unique ID string automatically if (and only if)
 * an ID value is <b>not</b> supplied within the Inventory Item string. If
 * an ID <b>is supplied</b> within the Inventory Item string then that ID
 * will be used <b>UNLESS</b> that particular ID already exists in which
 * case this method will not apply the addition and a message is displayed
 * to Console indicating as such.
 *
 * @param itemToAdd (String) The string to be supplied must be a forward
 *                  slash (<b>/</b>) delimited <b>String</b> consisting
 *                  consisting of the 4 data parts that make up any
 *                  particular Inventory Item:<pre>
 *
 *     1) The unique Item ID String (optional);
 *     2) The Item Name String;
 *     3) The Item Price (as a String);
 *     4) The Item Quantity (as a String).</pre><br>
 *
 * A typical Inventory Item String supplied to this method should look like:
 * <pre>
 *     "00006/LG LED 60\" Television/70555.0/08"</pre><br>
 *
 * Or it can look like (if an Auto-ID is requested):
 * <pre>
 *     "LG LED 60\" Television/70555.0/08"</pre><br>
 *
 * Providing duplicate ID's (an ID that is already in the database file or
 * records List) is not allowed.
 *
 * @return (Boolean) True if the addition is successful and False if not.
 */
public boolean addInventoryItem(String itemToAdd) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return false;
    }
    try {
        String[] itemParts = itemToAdd.split("\\s{0,}/\\s{0,}");

        // Is Auto-ID-Increment required?
        if (!itemParts[0].matches("\\d+") && itemParts.length == 3) {
            //Yes...
            String newID = getUniqueID();
            String[] parts = new String[4];
            parts[0] = newID;
            parts[1] = itemParts[0];
            parts[2] = itemParts[1];
            parts[3] = itemParts[2];
            itemParts = parts;
        }
        String id = itemParts[0];
        if (doesItemIDAlreadyExist(id)) {
            System.err.println("The Item ID (" + id + ") is an " + ErrorMsg.ID_EXISTS.msg);
            return false;
        }
        String name = itemParts[1];
        if (doesItemNameAlreadyExist(name)) {
            System.err.println("The Item Name (" + name + ") is an " + ErrorMsg.NAME_EXISTS.msg);
            return false;
        }
        double price = Double.parseDouble(itemParts[2]);
        int quant = Integer.parseInt(itemParts[3]);
        items.add(new InventoryItems(id, name, price, quant));
        refreshDataBase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean doesItemIDAlreadyExist(String id) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        res = false;
    }
    else {
        for (InventoryItems itms : items) {
            if (itms.getId().equals(id)) {
                res = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public boolean doesItemNameAlreadyExist(String name) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        res = false;
    }
    else {
        for (InventoryItems itms : items) {
            if (itms.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                res = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public String getUniqueID() {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    int max = 0;
    for (InventoryItems itms : items) {
        String idVal = itms.getId();
        if (!idVal.matches("\\d+")) {
            continue;
        }
        int val = Integer.parseInt(idVal);
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    if (max == 0) {
        return String.format("%5s", 1).replace(' ', '0');
    }
    else {
        return String.format("%5s", (max + 1)).replace(' ', '0');
    }
}

public String[] getAllInventoryItems(String... formatString) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    String format = "";
    if (formatString.length > 0) {
        format = formatString[0];
    }
    String[] itms = new String[items.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (!format.equals("")) {
            itms[i] = items.get(i).toString(format);
        }
        else {
            itms[i] = items.get(i).toString();
        }
    }
    return itms;
}

public String getItemID(String itemName) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    String res = null;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(itemName)) {
            res = item.getId();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void setItemID(String itemName, String newIDValue) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return;
    }

    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return;
    }
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(itemName)) {
            item.setId(newIDValue);
            break;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
}

public String getItemString(String idNumber) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    String res = null;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            res = item.toString();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public String getItemName(String idNumber) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    String res = null;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            res = item.getItemName();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void setItemName(String idNumber, String newName) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return;
    }
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            item.setItemName(newName);
            break;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
}

private double getItemPrice(String idNumber) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return 0.0d;
    }
    double res = 0.0d;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            res = item.getPrice();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void setItemPrice(String idNumber, double newPrice) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return;
    }
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            item.setPrice(newPrice);
            break;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
}

public int getItemQuantity(String idNumber) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return 0;
    }
    int res = 0;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            res = item.getQuantity();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void setItemQuantity(String idNumber, int newQuantity) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return;
    }
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            item.setQuantity(newQuantity);
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
}

public boolean loadDataFile() {
    boolean success;
    items.clear();  // Clear the Records Data List.

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(dataFile), encoding))) {
    // try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Trim the data line and remove BOM's (if any).
            line = trimBOMs(line);
            // Skip the header line and blank lines (if any).
            if (line.equals("") || line.toLowerCase().startsWith("id")) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s{0,}/\\s{0,}");
            // Validate record data types...
            String id = "";
            String name = "Unknown";
            double price = 0.0d;
            int quant = 0;
            if (lineParts.length >= 1) {
                // Is it an actual integer value string
                if (lineParts[0].matches("\\d+")) {
                    id = lineParts[0];
                }
                if (lineParts.length >= 2) {
                    // Does the string contain a name or is it empty.
                    name = (lineParts[1].equals("") ? "Unknown" : lineParts[1]);
                    if (lineParts.length >= 3) {
                        // Is it an actual integer or double/float value string
                        if (lineParts[2].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                            price = Double.parseDouble(lineParts[2]);
                        }
                        if (lineParts.length >= 4) {
                            // Is it an actual integer value string
                            if (lineParts[0].matches("\\d+")) {
                                quant = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[3]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            items.add(new InventoryItems(id, name, price, quant));
        }
        success = true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        success = false;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

public boolean saveItemsToFile() {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return false;
    }
    String header = String.format("%-8s%-27s%-10s%-5s%n", "ID", "Item Name", "Price", "Stocks");

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dataFile), encoding))) {
    // try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(dataFile))) {
        writer.append(header);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            String id = items.get(i).getId();
            String name = items.get(i).getItemName();
            double price = items.get(i).getPrice();
            int quant = items.get(i).getQuantity();
            String dataLine = String.format("%-6s/ %-25s/ %-8s/ %-4s%n", id, name, price, quant);
            writer.append(dataLine);
        }
        writer.flush();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void refreshDataBase() {
    saveItemsToFile();
    loadDataFile();

    // Call and method to update your JTable(s) here!
}

public boolean isIsInAdminMode() {
    return isInAdminMode;
}

public void setIsInAdminMode(boolean isInAdminMode) {
    this.isInAdminMode = isInAdminMode;
}

public String getDataFilePath() {
    return dataFile;
}

public void setDataFilePath(String dataFile) {
    this.dataFile = dataFile;
}

public String getEncoding() {
    return encoding;
}

public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
    this.encoding = encoding;
}

/**
 * Removes (trims away) leading and trailing white-spaces and Removes 
 * any BOM's (Byte Order Marks) from all the different Character Encodings.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param inputString (String) The Unicode string to remove BOM's from.<br>
 * 
 * @return (String) 
 */
private static String trimBOMs(String inputString) {
    inputString = inputString.trim()
            .replaceAll("\uFEFF|\uEFBBBF|\uFFFE|\u0000FEFF|\uFFFE0000|\u2B2F7638","")
            .replaceAll("\u2B2F7639|\u2B2F762B|\u2B2F762F|\u2B2F76382D|\uF7644C", "")
            .replaceAll("\uDD736673|\u0EFEFF|\uFBEE28|\u84319533", "");
    return inputString;
}

private void pressAnyKey(Scanner input) {
    System.out.println(ls + "Press Enter key to continue (q to quit)...");
    String anyKey = input.nextLine();
    if (anyKey.toLowerCase().equals("q")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Create a new Java Application project named **InventoryDemo** and copy/paste the supplied classes into it. This should give you an idea of how to create the tools to do what you need.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for helping me with my project. I ran and tested your code in a new java project and I got these errors (see post). I also renamed the classes into InventoryDemo and etc. Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If you created a new Java project (which you should do to run the code demo) then your project should have a **InventoryDemo.java** source file and a **InventoryItems.java** source file (two files). Package name must be the same in both source files whatever it is you are using. I just use: `package inventorydemo;`. What is on line **465** of the InventoryDemo.java source file? My code indicates a closing curley brace ( } ). The data file in in ANSI encoding.

Comment: I tried to understand what you mean by the closing curley brace. I've posted another picture above. What does it mean that the data file should be in ANSI encoding? And how do I set it up?

Comment: I have updated the InventoryDemo.java file so that in can read and write UTF-8 files. Copy/Paste the updated code and try again. It appears that the code is not reading your data file properly.

Comment: Hello! I replaced the code with the one you updated. I changed something in the `Constructor 2` from `Items` into `InventoryItems` and now it works wonderfully!

Am I correct that with this idea, I can modify it so that I can change records with the use of `JTextFields`?

Comment: My apologies. How embarrassing. I placed the update code for the **InventoryDemo.java** but forgot to place the code update for the **InventoryItems.java** class file (done now). You did the right thing @MarkzSnipe. As to your question: `I can modify it so that I can change records with the use of JTextFields?`. Absolutely! You can apply the selected record data to your JTextField's when clicking on a record within the JTable, make the modifications you want, then save those changes within the data file and JTable upon selecting a save button. I will make another post demonstrating this.

Comment: @DevilsHand Thank you so much! I forgot to accept this as an answer. Will wait for the nest post regarding JTextFields. For the meantime, thank you.

Comment: @MarkzSnipe - Update provided. I hope you can sort it out. I had to use several posts to do this. If you like I can email this to you via attachments.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing this from your part time. I'll ask questions so that I can understand anything fully. For now, I'll try to figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: I've got the code running and everything is fine! I created new categories like "Consoles" and I cannot seem to find the txt file created?

Comment: E-Mail sent containing the required source files.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the delay however I do have other, more pressing commitments.

As promised, here is a demo of how to utilize the methods contained within the **InventoryDemo** class against a form *similar* to what you have displayed within your post.

[image]

This runnable demo application is a quick works so don't expect any real optimization. That will be up to you as you create your own application. Simplicity makes for better understand-ability.

The runnable demo (named **DB_GUI**) below utilizes the classes supplied within my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61335775/4725875):

- InventoryItems Class (**InventoryItems.java**)
- InventoryDemo Class (**InventoryDemo.java**)

There has been a very minor adjustments made to the **InventoryDemo** class and the update has been made to that code in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61335775/4725875).

This runnable works like this:

You start with a blank database (no text files). Text data files are automatically created as they are needed and each file represents a specific Inventory Category, for example: **Writing Instruments**, **Game Consoles**, etc. These categories are created through the *editable* JComboBox located at the top of the application window. If a category is supplied in this JComboBox that is **not** already contained within the combo list then it is added to that list and a data file is created in preparation to hold inventory items related to that specific category.

The data files are created within a directory named **InventoryCategories** which is automatically created within your local file system in the **root** directory of the drive that your particular application is running on. *Make sure the appropriate permissions exist for such actions before attempting to run this demo application.*

To create Categories and Edit, Add, Save, or Delete data within the JTextFields of the form, Admin Access **must** be acquired. The only data item that can be modified by a regular User is the **Quantity** field. To go into Admin Mode, select the **Admin** link located directly under the JTable. You will be required to enter a password which is currently **1234**. You can change this password to whatever you like by modifying the string value contained within the **ADMIN_PASSWORD** class field variable in the code below.

**While In Admin Mode:**

- To edit an Inventory Item select it from within the Table then do
  whatever editing you like from the JTextFields. When done editing and
  to save your work, select the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.
- To add an Inventory Item to the current active Category, select the
  <kbd>Add</kbd> button. All the JTextField's will clear. Supply the
  required data within the form's JTextFields then when done select the
  <kbd>Save</kbd> button. That record will be saved (appended) to the
  related Data File and placed into the JTable. Supplying the Item **ID**
  is optional since if one is not supplied an ID will be auto-generated
  with a start ID of **00001**. You can not supply duplicate ID values
  within the same Category.
- To delete an Inventory Item from the current active Category, select
  the desired inventory item from within the JTable, the item will be
  displayed within the JTextFields located at the bottom section of the
  form. Select the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button. A confirmation dialog is
  display, select the <kbd>Yes</kbd> button to confirm deletion and the
  inventory item is deleted from both the data file and the JTable.

**To Disengage Admin Mode:**

Merely select the **Admin** link located at the bottom of JTable again. This link is a toggle to go in and out of Admin Mode.

**The Application Code:**

```
/*
Data text file names are based from the names of the categoryies 
created in Form. If a 'Writing Instruments' category is created 
then the data file created for that category's date will be named: 

                  Writing Instruments.txt

If a 'Game Consoles' category is created then the data file created 
for that category's date will be named: 

                     Game Consoles.txt

and so on. Categories are created by entering a specific category 
name (that DOES NOT already exist) into the Categories Drop-Down 
List (comboBox).
*/
package inventorydemo;

import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;



public class DB_GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final InventoryDemo demo = new InventoryDemo();
    private final String ADMIN_PASSWORD = "1234";
    private boolean appStarted = false;

public DB_GUI() {
    initComponents();

    fillCategoriesCombo();
    categoryComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);

    // Set the JTable's Header font size to match the JTable's font size.
    JTableHeader header = jTable1.getTableHeader();
    header.setFont(header.getFont().deriveFont((float) jTable1.getFont().getSize()));

    // Center Text in JTable Header Cells.
    alignJTableHeaderText(jTable1, 0);

    // Set JTable's Column Widths
    setJTableColumnWidths(jTable1, 13d, 62d, 15d, 10d);

    // Set JTable's background color to White.
    jTable1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().setBackground(Color.white);

    // Modifying the Look & Feel
    // Set JTable Header Background color to White.
    UIManager.getDefaults().put("TableHeader.background", Color.WHITE);
    // Remove JTable Header borders
    UIManager.getDefaults().put("TableHeader.cellBorder", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    // Set JTextField's inactive background color to White.
    UIManager.getDefaults().put("TextField.inactiveBackground", Color.WHITE);

    // Key Binding for Category Combo. Passes what was entered to 
    // the addNewCategory() method when the ENTER key is pressed.
    // Used to add new Categories.
    categoryComboBox.getEditor().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (demo.isInAdminMode()) {
                addNewCategory(categoryComboBox.getEditor().getItem().toString());
            }
            else {
                JFrame iFrame = new JFrame();
                iFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true); 
                iFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                iFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFrame, "You need Admin Access to "
                        + "create categories!", "Admin Required!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                iFrame.dispose();
            }
        }
    });

    // Center text in ComboBox.
    ((JLabel) categoryComboBox.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // Set startup focus to the Admin link.
    lblAdminAccess.requestFocus();
    appStarted = true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    productNameBox = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    categoryComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    productIDBox = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jSeparator5 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    productPriceBox = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jSeparator6 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    productQuantityBox = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    doneButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    deleteButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    addButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    lblAdminAccess = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lblStatus = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jSeparator3 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    jSeparator4 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
    lblItems = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setResizable(false);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Product ID:");
    jLabel1.setToolTipText("");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Price:");
    jLabel2.setToolTipText("");

    jSeparator1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    jSeparator1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    jSeparator1.setToolTipText("");
    jSeparator1.setName(""); // NOI18N
    jSeparator1.setOpaque(true);
    jSeparator1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    jSeparator1.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);

    productNameBox.setEditable(false);
    productNameBox.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    productNameBox.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    productNameBox.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    productNameBox.setToolTipText("");
    productNameBox.setBorder(null);
    productNameBox.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    productNameBox.setDisabledTextColor(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    productNameBox.setSelectionColor(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));

    categoryComboBox.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    categoryComboBox.setEditable(true);
    categoryComboBox.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    categoryComboBox.setAutoscrolls(true);
    categoryComboBox.setBorder(null);
    categoryComboBox.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
            categoryComboBoxItemStateChanged(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("Quantity:");

    jSeparator2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    jSeparator2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    jSeparator2.setToolTipText("");
    jSeparator2.setName(""); // NOI18N
    jSeparator2.setOpaque(true);
    jSeparator2.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    jSeparator2.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);

    productIDBox.setEditable(false);
    productIDBox.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    productIDBox.setToolTipText("");
    productIDBox.setBorder(null);

    jSeparator5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    jSeparator5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    jSeparator5.setToolTipText("");
    jSeparator5.setName(""); // NOI18N
    jSeparator5.setOpaque(true);
    jSeparator5.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    jSeparator5.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);

    productPriceBox.setEditable(false);
    productPriceBox.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));
    productPriceBox.setBorder(null);

    jSeparator6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    jSeparator6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    jSeparator6.setToolTipText("");
    jSeparator6.setName(""); // NOI18N
    jSeparator6.setOpaque(true);
    jSeparator6.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    jSeparator6.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);

    productQuantityBox.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
    productQuantityBox.setBorder(null);

    jScrollPane1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jScrollPane1.setBorder(null);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportBorder(null);
    jScrollPane1.setOpaque(true);

    jTable1.setBorder(null);
    jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    jTable1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "ID", "Product Name", "Price", "Qty"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Integer.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jTable1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    jTable1.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    jTable1.setOpaque(false);
    jTable1.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    jTable1.setSelectionForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jTable1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jTable1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jTable1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            jTable1KeyReleased(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    saveButton.setText("Save");
    saveButton.setEnabled(false);
    saveButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            saveButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    doneButton.setText("Done");
    doneButton.setToolTipText("");
    doneButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            doneButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    deleteButton.setText("Delete");
    deleteButton.setToolTipText("");
    deleteButton.setEnabled(false);
    deleteButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            deleteButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    addButton.setText("Add");
    addButton.setToolTipText("");
    addButton.setEnabled(false);
    addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    lblAdminAccess.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 10)); // NOI18N
    lblAdminAccess.setForeground(java.awt.Color.blue);
    lblAdminAccess.setText("<html><u>Admin</u></html>");
    lblAdminAccess.setToolTipText("<html> Turn Admin Mode: <font color=red>ON</font> </html> ");
    lblAdminAccess.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    lblAdminAccess.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            lblAdminAccessMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    lblStatus.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    lblStatus.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    lblStatus.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    lblStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblStatus.setText("<html>Add or select a product category (Admin required to add).</html>");
    lblStatus.setToolTipText("");
    lblStatus.setBorder(null);
    lblStatus.setOpaque(true);

    jSeparator3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));
    jSeparator3.setToolTipText("");

    jSeparator4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 153));
    jSeparator4.setToolTipText("");

    lblItems.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
    lblItems.setText("<html>Items: <font color=blue>0</font></html>");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 72, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(productIDBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(productPriceBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(productQuantityBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(productNameBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 238, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addComponent(lblStatus)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblItems, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lblAdminAccess, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 337, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                            .addComponent(categoryComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 285, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                            .addComponent(saveButton)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(addButton)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(deleteButton)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(doneButton)))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
        .addComponent(jSeparator3)
        .addComponent(jSeparator4)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
            .addComponent(categoryComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 212, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(lblAdminAccess, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(lblItems, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(4, 4, 4)
            .addComponent(productNameBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 18, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(24, 24, 24)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(productIDBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(productPriceBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 16, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(productQuantityBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jSeparator3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(saveButton)
                .addComponent(doneButton)
                .addComponent(deleteButton)
                .addComponent(addButton))
            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
            .addComponent(jSeparator4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(lblStatus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Because the code is so large I provide it in two posts. Just copy/paste the code in the next post directly below this code.

Answer (score 1):

**The remaining code for the post below:**

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    fillProductBoxes();
    lblStatus.setText("<html><center>View or edit fields.</center></html>");
}                                    

private void lblAdminAccessMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    // Admin label foreground color is Blue
    if (lblAdminAccess.getForeground().getRGB() == -16776961) {
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center>Provide Admin Password!</center></html>");
        String passWrd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "<html>Please provide "
                + "your <font color=magenta>Admin</font> Password:<br><br></html>",
                "Admin Password", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (passWrd == null) {
            lblStatus.setText("");
            return;
        }
        if (!passWrd.equals(ADMIN_PASSWORD)) {
            lblStatus.setText("<html><center>Invalid Admin password supplied!</center></html>");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html><center><b>You have supplied an Invalid "
                                        + "Password!</b></center><br></html>",
                                        "Invalid Password!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        lblAdminAccess.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
        lblAdminAccess.setToolTipText("<html> Turn Admin Mode: <font color=red>OFF</font> </html>");
        demo.setIsInAdminMode(true);
        setFormForAdminEditing(true);
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center>In Admin Mode!</center></html>");
    }

    else {
        lblAdminAccess.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        lblAdminAccess.setToolTipText("<html> Turn Admin Mode: <font color=red>ON</font> </html>");
        setFormForAdminEditing(false);
        demo.setIsInAdminMode(false);
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center>Released from Admin Mode!</center></html>");
    }

}                                           

private void doneButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.exit(0);
}                                          

private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (productNameBox.getText().equals("")
            || productPriceBox.getText().equals("")
            || productQuantityBox.getText().equals("")) {
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center><b>A required field is empty!</b></center></html>");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html>A required field is empty! All fields<br>"
                + "(except the <font color=blue>ID</font> field) must be "
                + "supplied!<br><br><font size='2'><center>The "
                + "<font color=red>ID</font> field is optional."
                + "</center></font><br><br></html>", "Field Empty!",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    // If it's just an edit...
    if (!InventoryDemo.items.isEmpty() && jTable1.getSelectedRow() != -1 && 
            productIDBox.getText().equals(InventoryDemo.items.get(jTable1.getSelectedRow()).getId())) {
        InventoryDemo.items.get(jTable1.getSelectedRow()).setItemName(productNameBox.getText());
        if (productIDBox.getText().equals("")) {
            productIDBox.setText(demo.getUniqueID());
        }
        else {
            productIDBox.setText(String.format("%5s", productIDBox.getText()).replace(' ', '0'));
        }
        InventoryDemo.items.get(jTable1.getSelectedRow()).setId(productIDBox.getText());
        InventoryDemo.items.get(jTable1.getSelectedRow()).setPrice(Double.parseDouble(productPriceBox.getText()));
        InventoryDemo.items.get(jTable1.getSelectedRow()).setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(productQuantityBox.getText()));
        demo.refreshDataBase();
        lblItems.setText("<html>Items: <font color=blue>" + fillJTableFromList(jTable1) + "</font></html>");
        lblStatus.setText("<html><b><center><font color=red>Item Saved!</font></center></b></html>");
        return;
    }

    else if (!productIDBox.getText().equals("") && demo.getItemName(productIDBox.getText()) != null) {
        String existingItemName = demo.getItemName(productIDBox.getText());
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center><b>Item ID Already Exists In Database!</b></center></html>");
        int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "<html>The ID supplied already "
                + "exists for another product item<br>named:<br><center><font color=blue>"
                + existingItemName + "</font></center><br>You can not change an ID of "
                + "this particualar product unless<br>the ID is <b>unique</b> (does not "
                + "already exist).<br><br><center>Do you want to auto-generate a unique "
                + "ID?</center><br><br></html>", "Invalid ID Supplied",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        if (res != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            return;
        }
        // Set a Unique ID number
        productIDBox.setText(demo.getUniqueID());
    }

    // Get a unique ID number if one isn't provided.
    if (productIDBox.getText().equals("")) {
        productIDBox.setText(demo.getUniqueID());
    }
    else {
        // Make sure the Product ID has the proper 0 padding (for example: 00012).
        productIDBox.setText(String.format("%5s", productIDBox.getText()).replace(' ', '0'));
    }

    demo.addInventoryItem(new StringBuffer("").append(productIDBox.getText()).append("/")
            .append(productNameBox.getText()).append("/")
            .append(productPriceBox.getText()).append("/")
            .append(productQuantityBox.getText()).toString());
    demo.refreshDataBase();
    lblItems.setText("<html>Items: <font color=blue>" + fillJTableFromList(jTable1) + "</font></html>");
    lblStatus.setText("<html><b><center><font color=red>Item Saved!</font></center></b></html>");
}                                          

private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    clearFields();
    productNameBox.requestFocus();
    lblStatus.setText("<html><center>Add desired Item (ID is optional).</center></html>");
}                                         

private void categoryComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                  
    // Ignore firings when combo is getting filled.
    if (!appStarted) {
        return;
    }
    String selected = categoryComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (selected == null || selected.equals("")) {
        return;
    }
    // If an attempt is made to create a category without admin rights
    if (!demo.isInAdminMode() && !new File("/InventoryCategories/" + selected + ".txt").exists()) {
        return;
    }
    demo.setDataFilePath("/InventoryCategories/" + selected + ".txt");
    clearFields();
    clearJTable(jTable1);
    if (demo.loadDataFile()) {
        lblItems.setText("<html>Items: <font color=blue>" + fillJTableFromList(jTable1) + "</font></html>");
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center>View or edit desired Item.</center></html>");
    }
    else {
        lblStatus.setText("<html>Loading of data file (<font color=red>" + selected + ".txt</font>) failed to carry out!</html>");
    }
}                                                 

private void jTable1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
    if ((evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || 
                            evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && 
                            jTable1.getRowCount() >= 0) {
        fillProductBoxes();
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center>View or edit fields.</center></html>");
    }
}                                   

private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    if (InventoryDemo.items.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "There are no Inventory Items to delete!", 
                                      "Nothing To Delete", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (jTable1.getSelectedRow() == -1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "There is no Inventory Item Selected To Delete!", 
                                      "Nothing Selected To Delete", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "<html>Are you sure you want "
                + "to delete the item:<br><br><font color=blue><b><center>" + 
                InventoryDemo.items.get(jTable1.getSelectedRow()).getItemName() + 
                "</b></font><br><center>from database for this Category?" + "<br><br><font size='2'>"
                + "<center>There is no <b>Undo</b> for this action!</font><br><br></html>", 
                "Delete Record?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    }
    else {
        InventoryDemo.items.remove(jTable1.getSelectedRow());
        demo.refreshDataBase();
        clearFields();
        lblItems.setText("<html>Items: <font color=blue>" + fillJTableFromList(jTable1) + "</font></html>");
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center><b>Item Deleted!</b></center></html>");
    }
}                                            

private void addNewCategory(String categoryName) {
    if (!demo.isInAdminMode()) {
        lblStatus.setText("<html<center><b>Admin rights required!</b></center></html>");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html>You must have <b>Administrator Rights</b> to add<br>"
                + "Categories to the database!<br><br></html>", "Admin Required!",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        categoryComboBox.getEditor().setItem("");
        return;
    }
    String dataFileName = "/InventoryCategories/" + categoryName.trim() + ".txt";
    if (new File(dataFileName).exists()) {
        lblStatus.setText("<html><center><b>Category Already Exists!</b></center></html>");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The Category named '" + categoryName
                + "' already exits!", "New Category Error!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    else {
        lblStatus.setText("");
        int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "<html>The Category named "
                + "'<font color=blue>" + categoryName + "</font>' does not exist."
                + "<br><br><center>Do you want to create it?</center><br><br></html>",
                "Create Category?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (res != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            demo.setDataFilePath(dataFileName);
        }
    }

    lblStatus.setText("<html>New category named <font color=blue>" + categoryName
            + "</font> was created.</html>");
    categoryComboBox.addItem(categoryName);
    categoryComboBox.revalidate(); categoryComboBox.repaint();
    categoryComboBox.setSelectedItem(categoryName);
    demo.loadDataFile();
}

private void clearFields() {
    productNameBox.setText("");
    productIDBox.setText("");
    productPriceBox.setText("");
    productQuantityBox.setText("");
}

private void setFormForAdminEditing(boolean onOff) {
    productNameBox.setEditable(onOff);
    productIDBox.setEditable(onOff);
    productPriceBox.setEditable(onOff);
    saveButton.setEnabled(onOff);
    addButton.setEnabled(onOff);
    deleteButton.setEnabled(onOff);

    if (onOff) {
        productNameBox.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        productIDBox.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        productPriceBox.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        productNameBox.requestFocus();
    }
    else {
        productNameBox.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        productIDBox.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        productPriceBox.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        jTable1.requestFocus();
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new DB_GUI().startApp(args);
}

private void startApp(String[] args) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new DB_GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });


}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void fillCategoriesCombo() {
    File files = new File("/InventoryCategories");
    if (!files.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    final List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] categories = getFilesListFromDirectory("/InventoryCategories", true);
    values.addAll(Arrays.asList(categories));
    categoryComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(values.toArray()));
}

private int fillJTableFromList(JTable table) {
    clearJTable(jTable1);

    if (InventoryDemo.items.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html>There are currently no inventory "
                              + "items<br>for this category!<br><br></html>", 
                              "No Inventory", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        return 0;
    }

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int recordCount = 0;
    table.removeAll();

    // Clear current table rows
    while (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            model.removeRow(i);
        }
    }

    // Fill the JTable Model.
    Object[] dataArray = new Object[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < InventoryDemo.items.size(); i++) {
        dataArray[0] = InventoryDemo.items.get(i).getId();
        dataArray[1] = InventoryDemo.items.get(i).getItemName();
        dataArray[2] = InventoryDemo.items.get(i).getPrice();
        dataArray[3] = InventoryDemo.items.get(i).getQuantity();
        model.addRow(dataArray);
        recordCount++;
    }
    return recordCount;

}

private void fillProductBoxes() {
    int selRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    if (selRow < 0) {
        return;
    }
    String id = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(selRow, 0);
    String name = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(selRow, 1);
    String price = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(selRow, 2));
    String qty = String.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(selRow, 3));

    productNameBox.setText(name);
    productIDBox.setText(id);
    productPriceBox.setText(price);
    productQuantityBox.setText(qty);
}

/**
 * Returns a String Array containing all the file names that are contained
 * within the supplied folder (directory) path. This method does not check
 * nested folders. Sub-Folders are ignored during the process.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * The file names string array that is returned can be made to return the
 * file names with name extensions removed if the optional
 * removeFileExtension parameter is supplied a boolean true.<br>
 *
 * @param directoryPath       (String) The directory to get file names
 *                            from.<br>
 *
 * @param removeFileExtension (Optional - Boolean - Default is False) Read
 *                            above information.<br>
 *
 * @return (1D String Array) A String Array containing all the file names
 *         found within the supplied folder path.
 */
public static String[] getFilesListFromDirectory(String directoryPath, boolean... removeFileExtension) {
    File file = new File(directoryPath);
    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        System.err.println("getFilesListFromDirectory() Method Error! "
                + "The supplied directoy path does not lead to a directory!"
                + System.lineSeparator() + "(" + directoryPath + ")"
                + System.lineSeparator());
        return null;
    }
    boolean noExtension = false;
    if (removeFileExtension.length > 0) {
        noExtension = removeFileExtension[0];
    }
    String[] files = file.list();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : files) {
        if (new File(file.getPath() + File.separator + string).isFile()) {
            if (noExtension) {
                if (string.lastIndexOf(".") > 0) {
                    if (string.split("\\.\\.").length > 1) {
                        list.add(string);
                    }
                    else {
                        list.add(string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf(".")));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    list.add(string);
                }
            }
            else {
                list.add(string);
            }
        }
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public static void clearJTable(JTable theTable) {
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) theTable.getModel();
    while (dtm.getRowCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtm.getRowCount(); i++) {
            dtm.removeRow(i);
        }
    }
}

public static void alignJTableHeaderText(JTable theTable, int alignType) {
    // Alignment options are: Align_LEFT (2), Align_CENTER (0), Align_RIGHT (4),
    // Align_LEADING (10), or Align_TRAILING (11)
    for (int i = 0; i < theTable.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        theTable.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(i)
                .setHeaderRenderer(new HeaderRenderer(theTable, alignType));
    }
}

/**
 * Set the pixel widths for the supplied Table Columns by way of
 * percentage.<br><br>
 *
 * @param table            (JTable) The JTable variable name.<br>
 *
 * @param widthPercentages (Double) Double values need to be supplied.
 *                         Consider the JTable being a width of 100%. When
 *                         supplying width percentages for all columns then
 *                         the sum of all percentages supplied should equal
 *                         100% (although not absolutely necessary).
 */
public static void setJTableColumnWidths(JTable table, double... widthPercentages) {
    int tablePreferredWidth = table.getParent().getSize().width; //.getPreferredSize().width;
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
        total += widthPercentages[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        column.setPreferredWidth((int) (tablePreferredWidth * (widthPercentages[i] / total)));
    }
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> categoryComboBox;
private javax.swing.JButton deleteButton;
private javax.swing.JButton doneButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator3;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator4;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator5;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator6;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblAdminAccess;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblItems;
private javax.swing.JLabel lblStatus;
private javax.swing.JTextField productIDBox;
private javax.swing.JTextField productNameBox;
private javax.swing.JTextField productPriceBox;
private javax.swing.JTextField productQuantityBox;
private javax.swing.JButton saveButton;
// End of variables declaration                   
}

Renderer SubClass ***">
class HeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer;
int horAlignment;

public HeaderRenderer(JTable table, int horizontalAlignment) {
    horAlignment = horizontalAlignment;
    renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
    Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
    JLabel label = (JLabel) c;
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(horAlignment);
    return label;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not update the **InventoryDemo** class code in my previous post so I will do it here:

```
package inventorydemo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class InventoryDemo {

public enum ErrorMsg {
    LOAD_ERR("Inventory Items have not been loaded in yet!"),
    NOT_ADMIN("Invalid Operation! Admin Status Required!"),
    ID_EXISTS("Invalid ID! That ID Already Exists!"),
    NAME_EXISTS("Invalid Item Name! That Name Already Exists!");

    String msg;

    ErrorMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String msg() {
        return msg;
    }

}

private String encoding = "UTF-8"; // options: "US-ASCII", "UTF-8", "UTF-16"
public static List<InventoryItems> items = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean isInAdminMode = false;
private String dataFile = "";
private String ls = System.lineSeparator();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // App is started this way to avoid the need for statics.
    new InventoryDemo().startApp(args);
}

private void startApp(String[] args) {
    if (!loadDataFile()) {
        System.err.println("Error Loading: " + dataFile);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This code is run from the startApp() method" + ls 
                     + "located within the InventoryDemo class. Its" + ls
                     + "intent is to demonstrate the how the methods" + ls
                     + "withint this class function." );
    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println("Available Inventory Items");
    System.out.println("=========================");
    String[] allItems = getAllInventoryItems();
    if (allItems != null) {
        for (String strg : allItems) {
            System.out.println(strg);
        }
    }

    pressAnyKey(input);

    showFormattedTable();

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Available Inventory Items (with formated ID & Name)");
    String header = String.format("%-7s %-26s", "ID", "Item Name");
    String topLine = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "="));
    String underline = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"));
    System.out.println(topLine);
    System.out.println(header);
    System.out.println(underline);
    allItems = getAllInventoryItems("%-7s %-26s");
    if (allItems != null) {
        for (String strg : allItems) {
            System.out.println(strg);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(topLine);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific Record (by ID: 00004)");
    System.out.println("=========================================");
    String itemString = getItemString("00004");
    System.out.println(itemString);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific ID (by Name: Playstation 4 Pro)");
    System.out.println("===================================================");
    itemString = getItemID("Playstation 4 Pro");
    System.out.println(itemString);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific Name (by ID: 00004)");
    System.out.println("=======================================");
    itemString = getItemName("00004");
    System.out.println(itemString);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific Price (by ID: 00003)");
    System.out.println("========================================");
    double itemprice = getItemPrice("00003");
    System.out.println(itemprice);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Retrieve A Specific Quantity (by ID: 00002)");
    System.out.println("===========================================");
    int itemQuant = getItemQuantity("00002");
    System.out.println(itemQuant);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Change Name for: 'Playstation 4 Pro' at ID: "
            + "'00003' TO 'Some Kinda Game-Box'");
    System.out.println("============================================"
            + "================================");
    itemString = getItemString("00003");
    System.out.println("Current Name: -->  " + itemString);
    setItemName("00003", "Some Kinda Game-Box");
    itemString = getItemString("00003");
    System.out.println("Name is Now:  -->  " + itemString);

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    String itemToAdd = "00006/LG LED 60\" Television/70555.0/08";
    System.out.println("Add a new Inventory Item (duplicate ID's are not allowed).");
    System.out.println("Adding (with 'NO Auto-ID-Increment'): "
            + itemToAdd);
    System.out.println("======================================"
            + "======================================");
    if (addInventoryItem(itemToAdd)) {
        showFormattedTable();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not add (" + itemToAdd + ") to Records List!");
    }

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    itemToAdd = "DYSON 430 Vacume/65437.0/6";
    System.out.println("Add a new Inventory Item (duplicate ID's are not allowed).");
    System.out.println("Adding (with 'Auto-ID-Increment'): "
            + itemToAdd);
    System.out.println("======================================"
            + "=======================");
    if (addInventoryItem(itemToAdd)) {
        showFormattedTable();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not add (" + itemToAdd + ") to Records List!");
    }

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Delete an Inventory Item ID (based on Item ID: 00006).");
    String itemIDToDelete = "00006";
    if (deleteInventoryItemID(itemIDToDelete)) {
        showFormattedTable();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not delete record ID (" + itemIDToDelete + ") from Records List!");
    }

    pressAnyKey(input);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Delete an Inventory Item Name (based on Item Name: DYSON 430 Vacume).");
    String itemNameToDelete = "DYSON 430 Vacume";
    if (deleteInventoryItemName(itemNameToDelete)) {
        showFormattedTable();
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Could not delete record Item Name (" + itemNameToDelete + ") from Records List!");
    }
}

private void showFormattedTable() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("   Available Inventory Items (with formatting)");
    String header = String.format("%-7s %-26s %-8s %-5s", "ID", "Item Name", "Price", "Stock");
    String topLine = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "="));
    String underline = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-"));
    System.out.println(topLine);
    System.out.println(header);
    System.out.println(underline);
    String[] allItems = getAllInventoryItems("%-7s %-26s $%-9s %-5s");
    if (allItems != null) {
        for (String strg : allItems) {
            System.out.println(strg);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(topLine);
}

/**
 * Deletes the Inventory Item in Records List and data file that contains the 
 * supplied Item ID.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param idToDelete (String) The ID Number of the record to delete.<br>
 * 
 * @return (Boolean) True if successful and False if not.
 */
public boolean deleteInventoryItemID(String idToDelete) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return false;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).getId().equals(idToDelete)) {
            items.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
    return true;
}

/**
 * Deletes ALL Inventory Items in Records List and data file that contains the 
 * supplied Item Name.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param nameToDelete (String) The Item Name to delete (case insensitive).<br>
 * 
 * @return (Boolean) True if successful and False if not.
 */
public boolean deleteInventoryItemName(String nameToDelete) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return false;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameToDelete)) {
            items.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
    return true;
}

/**
 * Admin Rights required!<br><BR>
 * <p>
 * Adds a Inventory Item to the Records List and database file.<br><br>
 * This method can produce a unique ID string automatically if (and only if)
 * an ID value is <b>not</b> supplied within the Inventory Item string. If
 * an ID <b>is supplied</b> within the Inventory Item string then that ID
 * will be used <b>UNLESS</b> that particular ID already exists in which
 * case this method will not apply the addition and a message is displayed
 * to Console indicating as such.
 *
 * @param itemToAdd (String) The string to be supplied must be a forward
 *                  slash (<b>/</b>) delimited <b>String</b> consisting
 *                  consisting of the 4 data parts that make up any
 *                  particular Inventory Item:<pre>
 *
 *     1) The unique Item ID String (optional);
 *     2) The Item Name String;
 *     3) The Item Price (as a String);
 *     4) The Item Quantity (as a String).</pre><br>
 *
 * A typical Inventory Item String supplied to this method should look like:
 * <pre>
 *     "00006/LG LED 60\" Television/70555.0/08"</pre><br>
 *
 * Or it can look like (if an Auto-ID is requested):
 * <pre>
 *     "LG LED 60\" Television/70555.0/08"</pre><br>
 *
 * Providing duplicate ID's (an ID that is already in the database file or
 * records List) is not allowed.
 *
 * @return (Boolean) True if the addition is successful and False if not.
 */
public boolean addInventoryItem(String itemToAdd) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return false;
    }
    try {
        String[] itemParts = itemToAdd.split("\\s{0,}/\\s{0,}");

        // Is Auto-ID-Increment required?
        if (!itemParts[0].matches("\\d+") && itemParts.length == 3) {
            //Yes...
            String newID = getUniqueID();
            String[] parts = new String[4];
            parts[0] = newID;
            parts[1] = itemParts[0];
            parts[2] = itemParts[1];
            parts[3] = itemParts[2];
            itemParts = parts;
        }
        String id = itemParts[0];
        if (doesItemIDAlreadyExist(id)) {
            System.err.println("The Item ID (" + id + ") is an " + ErrorMsg.ID_EXISTS.msg);
            return false;
        }
        String name = itemParts[1];
        if (doesItemNameAlreadyExist(name)) {
            System.err.println("The Item Name (" + name + ") is an " + ErrorMsg.NAME_EXISTS.msg);
            return false;
        }
        double price = Double.parseDouble(itemParts[2]);
        int quant = Integer.parseInt(itemParts[3]);
        items.add(new InventoryItems(id, name, price, quant));
        refreshDataBase();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean doesItemIDAlreadyExist(String id) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        res = false;
    }
    else {
        for (InventoryItems itms : items) {
            if (itms.getId().equals(id)) {
                res = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public boolean doesItemNameAlreadyExist(String name) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        res = false;
    }
    else {
        for (InventoryItems itms : items) {
            if (itms.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                res = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public String getUniqueID() {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        return "00001";
    }
    int max = 0;
    for (InventoryItems itms : items) {
        String idVal = itms.getId();
        if (!idVal.matches("\\d+")) {
            continue;
        }
        int val = Integer.parseInt(idVal);
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    }
    if (max == 0) {
        return String.format("%5s", 1).replace(' ', '0');
    }
    else {
        return String.format("%5s", (max + 1)).replace(' ', '0');
    }
}

public String[] getAllInventoryItems(String... formatString) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    String format = "";
    if (formatString.length > 0) {
        format = formatString[0];
    }
    String[] itms = new String[items.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (!format.equals("")) {
            itms[i] = items.get(i).toString(format);
        }
        else {
            itms[i] = items.get(i).toString();
        }
    }
    return itms;
}

public String getItemID(String itemName) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    String res = null;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(itemName)) {
            res = item.getId();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void setItemID(String itemName, String newIDValue) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return;
    }

    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return;
    }
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase(itemName)) {
            item.setId(newIDValue);
            break;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
}

public String getItemString(String idNumber) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    String res = null;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            res = item.toString();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public String getItemName(String idNumber) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return null;
    }
    String res = null;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            res = item.getItemName();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void setItemName(String idNumber, String newName) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return;
    }
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            item.setItemName(newName);
            break;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
}

private double getItemPrice(String idNumber) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return 0.0d;
    }
    double res = 0.0d;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            res = item.getPrice();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void setItemPrice(String idNumber, double newPrice) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return;
    }
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            item.setPrice(newPrice);
            break;
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
}

public int getItemQuantity(String idNumber) {
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return 0;
    }
    int res = 0;
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            res = item.getQuantity();
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

public void setItemQuantity(String idNumber, int newQuantity) {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return;
    }
    if (items.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.LOAD_ERR.msg);
        return;
    }
    for (InventoryItems item : items) {
        if (item.getId().equals(idNumber)) {
            item.setQuantity(newQuantity);
        }
    }
    refreshDataBase();
}

public boolean loadDataFile() {
    // See if the data file exists. If it doesn't then create it. 
    // This will also create the the path to the file if it doesn't 
    // already exist.
    if (!new File(dataFile).exists()) {
        createPathAndTextFile(dataFile);
        items.clear();  // Clear the Records Data List so to start fresh.
        return true; // Nothing in file at this point so, we exit method.
    }

    boolean success;
    items.clear();  // Clear the Records Data List.

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(dataFile), encoding))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Trim the data line and remove BOM's (if any).
            line = trimBOMs(line);
            // Skip the header line and blank lines (if any).
            if (line.equals("") || line.toLowerCase().startsWith("id")) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s{0,}/\\s{0,}");
            // Validate record data types...
            String id = "";
            String name = "Unknown";
            double price = 0.0d;
            int quant = 0;
            if (lineParts.length >= 1) {
                // Is it an actual integer value string
                if (lineParts[0].matches("\\d+")) {
                    id = lineParts[0];
                }
                if (lineParts.length >= 2) {
                    // Does the string contain a name or is it empty.
                    name = (lineParts[1].equals("") ? "Unknown" : lineParts[1]);
                    if (lineParts.length >= 3) {
                        // Is it an actual integer or double/float value string
                        if (lineParts[2].matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                            price = Double.parseDouble(lineParts[2]);
                        }
                        if (lineParts.length >= 4) {
                            // Is it an actual integer value string
                            if (lineParts[0].matches("\\d+")) {
                                quant = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[3]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            items.add(new InventoryItems(id, name, price, quant));
        }
        success = true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        success = false;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}

public boolean saveItemsToFile() {
    if (!isInAdminMode) {
        System.err.println(ErrorMsg.NOT_ADMIN.msg);
        return false;
    }
    String header = String.format("%-8s%-27s%-10s%-5s%n", "ID", "Item Name", "Price", "Stocks");

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(dataFile), encoding))) {
        writer.append(header);
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            String id = items.get(i).getId();
            String name = items.get(i).getItemName();
            double price = items.get(i).getPrice();
            int quant = items.get(i).getQuantity();
            String dataLine = String.format("%-6s/ %-25s/ %-8s/ %-4s%n", id, name, price, quant);
            writer.append(dataLine);
        }
        writer.flush();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void refreshDataBase() {
    saveItemsToFile();
    loadDataFile();
}

/**
 * Will create the supplied path and text file into the local file system if
 * they do not already exist. If the path to file already does exist but the
 * file does not then just the file is created. Make sure file system
 * permissions are properly set before using this method. If an Exception is
 * encountered then false is returned.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * This method will return true if the supplied path and file name already
 * exist.
 *
 * @param pathString The path and file to create (if they don't already
 *                   exist).
 *
 * @return Boolean true or false. Returns true if the creation was
 *         successful and false if not successful.
 */
public static boolean createPathAndTextFile(String pathString) {
    if (pathString.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("createPathAndTextFile() - Path & Text File Created: " + false);
        return false;
    }
    if (new File(pathString).exists()) {
        return true;
    }
    String pathToFile = new File(pathString).getAbsolutePath().substring(0, new File(pathString).getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator));
    String fileToCreate = new File(pathString).getAbsolutePath().substring(new File(pathString).getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);

    try {
        //Make the directories path if it doesn't already exist...
        File dir = new File(pathToFile);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        //Make the text file...
        File file = new File(dir, fileToCreate);
        FileWriter newFile = new FileWriter(file);
        newFile.close();
        if (new File(pathString).exists()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("createPathAndTextFile() - Exception Encountered: " 
                            + System.lineSeparator() + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isInAdminMode() {
    return isInAdminMode;
}

public void setIsInAdminMode(boolean isInAdminMode) {
    this.isInAdminMode = isInAdminMode;
}

public String getDataFilePath() {
    return dataFile;
}

public void setDataFilePath(String dataFile) {
    this.dataFile = dataFile;
}

public String getEncoding() {
    return encoding;
}

public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
    this.encoding = encoding;
}

/**
 * Removes (trims away) leading and trailing white-spaces and Removes 
 * any BOM's (Byte Order Marks) from all the different Character Encodings.<br><br>
 * 
 * @param inputString (String) The Unicode string to remove BOM's from.<br>
 * 
 * @return (String) 
 */
private static String trimBOMs(String inputString) {
    inputString = inputString.trim()
            .replaceAll("\uFEFF|\uEFBBBF|\uFFFE|\u0000FEFF|\uFFFE0000|\u2B2F7638","")
            .replaceAll("\u2B2F7639|\u2B2F762B|\u2B2F762F|\u2B2F76382D|\uF7644C", "")
            .replaceAll("\uDD736673|\u0EFEFF|\uFBEE28|\u84319533", "");
    return inputString;
}

private void pressAnyKey(Scanner input) {
    System.out.println(ls + "Press Enter key to continue (q to quit)...");
    String anyKey = input.nextLine();
    if (anyKey.toLowerCase().equals("q")) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

There is a lot of code that can be removed from this class if it is actually used with the DB_GUI application.